# Change div border on input check

Tags: html, input, checkbox, border

link:http://jsfiddle.net/KM9bK/1/

```
$('.comprejuntoproduto input:checkbox').on('click', function (e) {
if ($('.comprejuntoproduto input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
$(".comprejuntoproduto").addClass("changeborder"); 
}else{
$(".comprejuntoproduto").parent().removeClass("changeborder"); 
}
});
```

I want when .compreprodutojunto input:checkbox is checked, change the .compreprodutojunto border style.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to actually include the jQuery library if you're going to use jQuery (not sure if this was a fiddle-only issue or not). If you didn't include jQuery in your actual page outside of jsFiddle, you'd do it like this:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

(Note, you can download your own copy if you prefer to host it yourself, or call it directly from `code.jquery.com`)

Also, when you call `.removeClass()` you can simply call it on the element that you had previously called `.addClass()` on, in this case `<div class="comprejuntoproduto">`.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/KM9bK/7/

```
$('.comprejuntoproduto input:checkbox').on('click', function (e) {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(".comprejuntoproduto").addClass("changeborder"); 
  } else {
    $(".comprejuntoproduto").removeClass("changeborder");  
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, works, but on my website isnt working, i dont know why.
Look that: http://www.brainmotion.com.br/sampa/single.php
Scroll down, and look the checkbox.

thanks again

Comment: You need to either place your JavaScript just before your closing `</body>` tag or wrap it in a `.ready()` method (or both!). The `.on()` method is firing before those elements exist and therefore isn't actually attaching to the checkbox, div, etc.: http://api.jquery.com/ready/